# How do I make Geshi formatting easily copyable?

Tags: mediawiki, geshi

I have installed the Geshi extension to allow for syntax highlighting on my MediaWiki-powered website. I am trying to figure out how to make syntax highlighting easily copyable.

Currently, when I try to copy code formatting, the line numbers get copied alongside the code:

[image]

I have tried looking at [Geshi options](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi) to no avail.

Comment: Have you considered turning off the line numbers?

Comment: That works, but I want line numbers too ...

Comment: What HTML could achieve that? As long it's a numbered list with ol, this sounds hard to fix. CSS? Tables?

Answer (score 0):

The GeSHi documentation talks about that in http://qbnz.com/highlighter/geshi-doc.html#line-numbers

```
$geshi->set_header_type(GESHI_HEADER_PRE_TABLE);
```